# Why are multiple 'fail' handlers being called when several 'then' handlers are chained to a deferred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

My project involves workflows that uses muliple API's that return deferred promises. I am using jQuery 1.8

I understand that the difference between `.done()` and `.then()` is that `.then()` returns a new promise. In my example, I would expect that if the first deferred was rejected, that only the first `.fail()` handler would be executed because the second is chained to the new promise. In execution, both fail handlers are executed.

```
var firstDeferred = $.Deferred(), secondDeferred = $.Deferred();

firstDeferred.promise()
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.then(function () {
    return secondDeferred.promise();
})
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

firstDeferred.reject('first deferred object');
//secondDeferred.reject('second deferred object');
```

My Expected Result:

```
> first deferred object
```

Actual Result:

```
> first deferred object
> first deferred object
```

Why are both `.fail()` handlers being called? How can I structure my workflow in a way that the the handlers are only called when the specific deferred promises are rejected?

Comment: jquery's deferred isn't really a great promise impl, I would recommend  using an impl that conforms to promises/a+ (https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/blob/master/implementations.md). What you can do in jQuery, is attach an error handler using the `then` method (second param, can't be done with `fail`), and with this function you can return a value, which will be passed to the next level's successHandler, you cannot wrap/alter the error however (possible in a promises/a+ impl) or block the error entirely. Promises must complete, either by error or success.

Comment: Gene C, if you chain two `.fail()` handlers then two fail handlers will fire unless there's something between them in the chain to provide a new promise with a different status. That "something" must be an appropriately written `.then()`. As written above, the intermediate `.then()` with no second argument will have no effect when `firstDeferred` is rejected; "fail" status will propagate straight through the `.then()` and the second `.fail()` handler will fire, exactly as you have observed.

Comment: @David McMullin, what you say is not 100% correct. jQuery's `.then()` allows a new promise to be returned from either of its handlers, thus allowing the status passed down the chain to be independent of the promise that fed the `.then()` from its left. But `.then()` handlers do not always behave in this way. Returning a non-promise will propagate the original promise's status but resolved/rejected with the returned value. Handlers with no return statement will cause the original promise to be propagated without change. Moving between different impls of Promises_A is indeed difficult.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot thanks for that extra info! I was testing in a sandbox and never thought to try returning yet another promise, thanks very much for pointing that out =)

Comment: @DavidMcMullin, you should see my attempts at using Q ..... not a pretty sight :(

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, haha, each to their own =) (if you're still interested in Q, this post is the most useful one I've ever read : http://domenic.me/2012/10/14/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/ )

Comment: @Flambino, agreed, I didn't say anything you hadn't already said. My bad.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin, I'm afraid I can't share your enthusiasm for that article. I'm just glad it's not the first thing I ever read on the subject, otherwise I may well have got no further. The author is particularly hung up on promises being something to do with throwing and catching - pardon! And whereas he must have something in mind, the bold statement "jQuery version is 1.9.1, and its promises implementation is completely broken with regard to the error handling semantics" is offered without explanation or context. One day maybe we'll see Domenic Denicola in the ring with John Resig .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not chaining anything to the promise you return in the `then()` callback, because that callback never gets executed.

`then()` takes these arguments:

```
then( doneFilter , failFilter )
```

Your callback is the 1st argument, hence it's the `doneFilter`. But the first promise fails, so `then()` doesn't call your callback. It *would* call the `failFilter`, but you don't pass anything for that 2nd argument.

Quoting from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

> If the filter function used is null, or not specified, the promise will be resolved or rejected with the same values as the original.

And since the `failFilter` argument isn't given, `then()` just forwards the state of the first promise, which triggers the 2nd `fail()` handler.

This works:

```
var firstDeferred  = $.Deferred(),
    secondDeferred = $.Deferred();

firstDeferred.promise()
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
.then(null, function () { // Notice the null
    return secondDeferred.promise();
})
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});

firstDeferred.reject('first deferred object');
secondDeferred.reject('second deferred object');
```

which logs:

```
first deferred object
second deferred object
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `then` return a new promise (which result is piped to the result of its callback returned promise).

A promise can have two final state: resolved or failed. So, as the first deferred failed, the second can never be resolved, so it fails. If `then` wasn't bubbling the failing, you'd found yourself with an indefinitely pending promise. This could be a risk for memory leaks.

Just changed the way you manage the `then` fail function if you only want it to be run if it has actually run.